# Argument type 'string | null' not assignable to parameter type 'string | number | boolean'

Tags: angular, typescript

Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | boolean'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean'.ts(2345)
(property) User.token: string | null

[image: interceptor]
[image: aurh-service]

Comment: You should explicitly ask the question(e.g.: "Why is compiler complaining about this" or "How can I bypass compiler from throwing error...") not just paste an error message. Only this way community can provide helpful and comprehensive explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can explicitly tell ts that this string is not null by the `!` bang operator, if you are really sure it will be there

```
.set('auth', user.token!)
```